# array passed as parameter to a WCF service to be filled up comes back full of null's

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to write a WCF pipe service. One of my service's methods will receive an `object[]` as a parameter and fill it up, emulating `IDataReader`'s `GetValues` method. But whenever I call this method from my client I get a full of `null` values array. I also tried changing the `object[]` parameter to `ref object[]` but nothing changes.

I've been doing some tests after first writing this question and this is weirder than I first though. The hole problem seems to occur in the client's side. Here is some code (all taken from client side):

```
object[] values = new object[reader.FieldCount];
// values is filled up with null's
reader.GetValues(values);
// values is again filled up with null's (see code bellow)
```

This is `GetValues`, called by the code above:

```
public int GetValues(object[] values)
{
    // values is filled out with null's, naturally
    return DatabaseProxy.Instance.GetValues(_ConnectionId, _ReaderId, ref values);
    // values has content here! (values[0] == "hello this is a string")
}
```

The `GetValues` method in `DatabaseProxy.Instance` is my server's method, which takes a `ref` parameter because otherwise it would return an array full of `null`s. By using the `ref` modifier, now it does return values, but then these values disappear inside my client. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Are you sure the web service is actually returning any values to the client?

Comment: Can you post your service method that returns the values? The service interface your service class implements and the code you use to call said method?

Comment: If you are going to pass values by ref, you have to use ref everywhere ... for example, you have to have ref here:  NewChannel.GetValues(connectionId, readerId, ref values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

Scrapped my previous answer and looked at google and other SO questions and came up with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733070.aspx)

It seems you can use ref, but you have to declare it in your service contract correctly for it to be used by WCF.

See the section *Out and Ref Parameters*

In which case your service side method should be declared

```
public int GetValues(int connectionId, int readerId, ref values)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure, but 99.9% sure that ref won't work in WCF the same way it does in memory. Return the array as your output rather than using a ref parameter.

Comment: But the `ref` is being only used internally by my server. My server's public method (the one being called by my client) doesn't use `ref`. I also tried using `ref` in my server's public method but still didn't work. I will use the array as a return type if I can't solve it another way.

Comment: You are sending an array to the server right? And then you are expecting the array to be filled with data after the call right? That's not going to work.

Comment: But it should :). When you make a WCF call, the data is serialized and sent over to the server (i.e., it's passed *by value*, not by reference). Then any results are serialized from the service and sent back to the client. The only result from your operation is the `int` which is being returned. By making the parameter `ref`, you're getting WCF to return, in addition to the `int` value, another copy of that array, and that will be deserialized an populated at the client.

Comment: @carlosfigueira I agree it will get sent to the WCF service as a parameter, but it won't return, surely WCF only serializes the return value of the method, it has no knowledge of the `ref` it should also return

Comment: @Chris: I'm about 99% sure at some point, while first writing the code and testing, I did get values back. Don't remember exactly how my code looked like though :(.

Comment: WCF does work with ref parameters. It treats them as a pair of in/out parameters.